# Shell script: time and python into a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I need to write a bash script, that executes a python program and i need to output the time of execution and the results in the same file. 
I **CAN NOT** edit the python code.

As there are multiple tests I want to execute them in  background. 
I've tried this

```
#!bin/bash
$(time python3 program.py file1 > solAndTimeFile1.txt &)
```

but it didn't work at all, it only outputs the python program results in the *solAndTimeFile1.txt* and the time is shown in the terminal.

I've also tried this:

```
#!bin/bash
$(time python3 program.py file1 > solAndTimeFile1.txt >> solAndTimeFile1.txt &)
```

Same output and makes even less sense to me.

Comment: https://explainshell.com/ is a great resource to deconstruct bash commands

Comment: love the idea of the web, definitely will help me improve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your command into curly braces so it is run in a subshell and you can capture its output. To redirect both stdout and stderr to a file use `&>file`. See `man bash` for further information.

```
{ time python3 program.py file1; } &>solAndTimeFile1.txt &
```